# Is [computer-science] a useful tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I stumbled upon a question inappropriately using the [computer-science](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-science) tag, and upon looking at other questions using that tag, found that a large number of questions using that tag do not seem to gain anything from using that tag. It seems to me that most of the questions currently using the tag could be retagged more specifically; for example, algorithm-related questions could be tagged [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) (or something even more specific, if applicable), or [grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grammar) for questions regarding formal grammars.

The tag wiki excerpt states:

> Computer science (CS) is the science behind programming. It is the study of the theoretical foundations of information and computation and of practical techniques for their implementation and application in computer systems.

Is [computer-science](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-science) a useful tag to keep, or should it be removed?

Comment: I’m now realizing that I was in the ‘needs answers’ view when looking at the list of questions in that tag, which hid some good questions and filtered it to lots of questions of poorer quality. Still, I’m not sure [tag:computer-science] is useful even when applied to better questions.

Comment: It's a bit like having a tag called "programming". It's on-topic, but not very informative.

Answer (score 10):

I Agree because most of what's discussed on SO could fall into the computer science tag, especially considering modular courses and as Andrew Grimm already pointed out, despite it's 'correctness' it isn't useful. There are other Stack Exchange sites now for other types of computer science questions such as Data Science, Computer Science etc.

Answer (score 7):

Right now, this tag is being used for all kinds of general programming questions with no consistency as to what its actual proper use is.

Furthermore, we already have separate sites for Computer Science and Theoretical Computer Science, so it's unclear what this tag's even for. Questions that are actually about "pure" computer science topics should presumably be asked on one of those sites instead, so this tag isn't even really describing something that's on topic here.

I say we burninate it.